# Return Value of Col A where col B is highest

Tags: google-sheets, formula

In *Google spreadsheet* I Have `col A` and `Col B`

```
Col A : Name of a person exemple
Col B : Grade
```

I want to be able to show the best result in the class is : XYZ

I've tried multiple formulas, but it always throws an error and can't find the solution.

I've included a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/3ejoueur.com/spreadsheets/d/1RZUis7FS3m4Mk6LS_OPH5Pabi_WRNy9G9HhPAlNiyws/edit?usp=sharing) for you all to help me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sheet can't be accessed, but in general you should be able to get the desired output by using filter() and max.

E.g:

```
=filter(A:A; B:B=max(B:B))
```

Note: depending on your locale you may have to replace the semi colon with a comma.

Comment: I change the access on the file, you should be able to see it. I try what you gave me but still have error.

Comment: I still can't access the file. Share it to 'anyone with the link' 'can edit'.  Oh I noticed an argument separator missing. Updated the formula. Sorry...

Comment: AWESOME !!! you did it !!! Thanks !!! Was using index, match all of those and was not working :)